# Filter in Daily cash Transactions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a daily cash transactions sheet which looks like this.
[image]
What formula do I have to put in F column so that when I apply filter datewise, I get a result like in the second picture? I have tried subtotal function but that worked fine except it could not pick the opening balance of previous day.

Main problem here is date in the column A is not continuous(otherwise lookup, index, match, offset, countif etc. could work)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot and finally came up with a solution. I put  formula.......=if(isblank(A2)=true,"", if(counta($A$2:A2)<>subtotal(3,$A$2:A2),subtotal(9,$D$2:D2)-subtotal(9,$E$2:E2)+sumif(A:A,"<"&A2,D:D)-sumif(A:A,"<"&A2,E:E),sum($D$2:D2)-sum($E$2:E2)))...... in F2.

Thank you Tetsujin for your editing.